# C programming under linux

Tags: c

I tried to run the following program from [gribblelab.org](http://gribblelab.org/CBootCamp/A2_Parallel_Programming_in_C.html) but got following error. the program is below:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <pthread.h>
    #define NTHREADS 5
    void *myFun(void *x)
     {
      int tid;
      tid = *((int *) x);
      printf("Hi from thread %d!\n", tid);
      return NULL;
     }

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
      pthread_t threads[NTHREADS];
      int thread_args[NTHREADS];
      int rc, i;
  /* spawn the threads */
      for (i=0; i<NTHREADS; ++i)
       {
        thread_args[i] = i;
        printf("spawning thread %d\n", i);
        rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, myFun, (void *) &thread_args[i]);
       }
  /* wait for threads to finish */
      for (i=0; i<NTHREADS; ++i) {
      rc = pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
     }
     return 1;
   }
```

the error i got was as follows when i tried to run in  ubuntu :
*undefined reference to pthread_create
undefined reference to pthread_join*

Comment: Are you compiling with `-pthread`? : something like `gcc -pthread -o demo demo.c`

Comment: Try compiling your code with the -lpthread flag.

Comment: @KeineLust: Note that the correct flag is `-pthread`, without it you will not get `-D_REENTRANT`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: Again, `-lpthread` is not correct, use `-pthread`

Comment: @DietrichEpp you are right

Comment: Thank you @Keine Lust , Your technique worked for me. Thank you very much sir.